# how to insert links into <div> tag

Tags: html

I need to add a hyperlink to a  tag and the following is what I did.

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    The new site is started, and old site is gone
     <a href='www.google.com' id='dialog'>Google</a>
</div>
```

I added the code to a "Script Editor" webpart, however,i found there is an issue that the link is changed to

"https://teams.connect.te.com/sites/PCINDIRECT/SitePages/www.google.com"

"https://teams.connect.te.com/sites/PCINDIRECT/SitePages" is the folder where the page is stored.
 Please instruct me how to change the code, so that, the hyperlink will be "www.goolge.com" correctly?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include **http://** in the href if you are pointing to some absolute URL, or use a / for relative Urls

**Absolute URL Reference**

```
<a href='http://www.google.com' id='dialog'>Google</a>
```

**Relative URL Reference**

```
<a href='/sites/PCINDIRECT/SitePages/something.aspx' id='dialog'>Google</a>
```